# It is possible for a closure to know of which function is an argument?

Tags: php, closures, parameter-passing

In the code below, is there a single way for `$bar()` to know that it was called being an argument of `foo()`:

```
// This function belongs to a 3er party library I don't have access to 
function foo( $baz ){
    // code here
}

// This is my function
$bar = function(){
    $argumentOf = ???;  // some dark magic here
    echo $argumentOf;   // print "foo"
    // more code goes here
    return "something interesting";
};

echo foo( $bar() );
```

I know that I could make `$bar()` to accept an argument and then call it like this:

```
foo( $bar( "foo" ) );
```

It is possible without explicitly passing the name of the function?

I tried [debug_backtrace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) to no avail.

Comment: The `$bar` function gets executed before `foo`, so you can't know what its result will be used for *later*.

Comment: In the second line, I'm assuming $baz is supposed to be $bar. Correct?

Comment: @Jeto - I know it. I tried `debug_backtrace` with very little hope. Still, it is called because PHP found `foo()` and is reading its arguments, so I wonder if somewhere there is trace about it.

Comment: @Ghoti - No, it is `$baz`. It could be whatever. It just points out that `foo()` has one parameter.

Comment: @Don'tPanic - I think I've seen them all :) `debug_backtrace` reports just `{closure}` as the current function name.